# dynamically change the model used as base for a qml item

Tags: qml, qt-quick

Im starting to work with qtquick 1.1. And i have designed a component consisting mainly out of a pathview.

```
Rectangle {
    id: pathViewElement

    PathView {
        id: pathView
        pathItemCount: 4
        preferredHighlightBegin: 0.5
        preferredHighlightEnd: 0.5
        highlightRangeMode: PathView.StrictlyEnforceRange
        model: myModel
        delegate: Item {
            width: valueText.width
            height: 50
            scale: 1.0-2*Math.abs(pathViewElement.width/2-(x+width/2)) / pathViewElement.width
            opacity: scale
            smooth: true
            Text {
                id: valueText
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: myModel.value
                font.pointSize: 35
            }
        }
        path: Path {
            startX: 0; startY: 25
            PathLine { x: pathViewElement.width; y: 25;}
        }
    }
}
```

This PathView is using a model called myModel. Which might be located in any other file.

The question now is the following:
I'm using the same component to be able to change different values. Each of these values is coming with another QML ListModel.
So how can i dynamically change the model used in the PathView (myModel)?

Also, while creating the PathView i can statically set the model using

```
model: MyListModel{}
```

where MyListModel is a qmlFile consisting only of a ListModel {} declaration. But when i dynamically create the PathView from within a third file, say MyApplication.qml I cannot set pathViewElement.model: MyListModel{} as the compiler is expecting a ";" instead of {}. Why is this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change QML GridView model by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501266/change-qml-gridview-model-by-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

> So how can i dynamically change the model used in the PathView
>   (myModel)?

On the occurrence of respective event, you can directly change the model assigned for your view.

eg. Assuming you want this change to be done on click of some mouse button:

```
onClicked:
{
   pathView.model = myNewModel
}
```

Here, myNewModel is the id for your new model to replace with.

> But when i dynamically create the PathView from within a third file,
>   say MyApplication.qml I cannot set pathViewElement.model:
>   MyListModel{} as the compiler is expecting a ";" instead of {}. Why is
>   this?

Can you state this part more clearly ?